# Laravel 7: Verify email using API endpoint + single page application

Tags: php, laravel, hmac, sha, laravel-7

I have a NuxtJS/Vue SPA and I want to verify the user email with the Laravel API that's my server side.

I create a custom notification called `VerifyEmail.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class VerifyEmail extends Notification {
    
    public function via($notifiable) {
        return ['mail'];
    }
    
    public function toMail($notifiable) {
        $params = [
            'id' => $notifiable->getKey(),
            'hash' => sha1($notifiable->getEmailForVerification()),
            'expiry' => Carbon::now()->addMinutes(60)->timestamp
        ];
        $url = config('app.web_client_url') . '/verify-email?';
        foreach ($params as $key => $param) {
            $url .= "{$key}={$param}&";
        }
        $key = config('app.key');
        $signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $url, $key);
        $url .= "signature=$signature";

        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject(Lang::get('Verify Email Address'))
            ->line(Lang::get('Please click the button below to verify your email address.'))
            ->action(Lang::get('Verify Email Address'), $url)
            ->line(Lang::get('If you did not create an account, no further action is required.'));
    }
}
```

In my registration controller when a user registers I use:

```
...
$user->save();
$user->notify(new VerifyEmail());
return response()->json([
    'message' => $user
], 201);
```

and the email gets sent. The URL in the email is something like: `https://localhost:7000/verify-email?id=37&hash=4c1691e6db623b85d90cee62f80d6f9085648c92&expiry=1595596017&signature=d6c6374b203b1da66d11818728921a4160e30ebf43c5a8be544220c8eca97bb3` (localhost:7000 is the address of my NuxtJS application).

Upon going to that page, I make the following request in the `mounted` lifecycle method:

```
this.signature = this.$route.query.signature
this.expiry = this.$route.query.expiry
this.hash = this.$route.query.hash
this.id = this.$route.query.id
this.$axios.$get(`api/email/verify/${this.id}?hash=${this.hash}&expiry=${this.expiry}&signature=${this.signature}`)
        .then(response => {
            this.successMessage = response
        }).catch(error => {
            this.errorMessage = error
        })
```

This request hits the endpoint on my server and the following method runs:

```
public function verify($user_id, Request $request) {
    if (!$request->hasValidSignature()) { // Check always fails and we get a 401 
        return response()->json(["msg" => "Invalid URL provided."], 401);
    }
    $user = User::findOrFail($user_id);
    if (!$user->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
        $user->markEmailAsVerified();
    }
    return response()->json(["msg" => "Email verified."], 200);
}
```

The route for laravel endpoint:

```
Route::get('email/verify/{id}', 'Api\EmailVerificationController@verify')->name('verification.verify');
```

I can see that the parameters are received in the `verify` method request object parameter (e.g. setting a breakpoint and checking):

[image]

The check for a valid signature always fails and results in a 401 being sent back to the client. What's wrong with the URL/signature that I'm generating?

Comment: try adding `dd($request->all())` in your `verify` method to check if the params are received propertly

Comment: I can see that the hash, expiry and signature are in the request object under query > parameters. I've updated the question with this info

Answer (score 1):

Here what I did  to solve the problem. Go to AuthServiceProvider

```
/**
   * Register any authentication / authorization services.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function boot()
  {
    $this->registerPolicies();

    //

    VerifyEmail::createUrlUsing(function ($notifiable) {
      $params = [
        "expires" => Carbon::now()
          ->addMinutes(60)
          ->getTimestamp(),
        "id" => $notifiable->getKey(),
        "hash" => sha1($notifiable->getEmailForVerification()),
      ];

      ksort($params);

      // then create API url for verification. my API have `/api` prefix,
      // so i don't want to show that url to users
      $url = \URL::route("verification.verify", $params, true);

      // get APP_KEY from config and create signature
      $key = config("app.key");
      $signature = hash_hmac("sha256", $url, $key);

      // generate url for yous SPA page to send it to user
      return env("APP_FRONT") .
        "/auth/verify-email/" .
        $params["id"] .
        "/" .
        $params["hash"] .
        "?expires=" .
        $params["expires"] .
        "&signature=" .
        $signature;
    });
  }
}
```

add this to api.php

```
Route::get("/verify-email/{id}/{hash}", [
    VerifyEmailController::class,
    "__invoke",
  ])
    ->middleware(["auth:sanctum","signed", "throttle:6,1"])
    ->name("verification.verify");
```

add this to VerifyEmailController.php

```
 /**
   * Mark the authenticated user's email address as verified.
   *
   * @param  \Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\EmailVerificationRequest  $request
   * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
   */
  public function __invoke(EmailVerificationRequest $request)
  {
    if ($request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
      return response()->json(
        [
          "message" => "Your'r email already verified.",
        ],
        Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
      );
    }

    if ($request->user()->markEmailAsVerified()) {
      event(new Verified($request->user()));
    }

    return response()->json(
      [
        "message" => "Verification complete thank you.",
      ],
      Response::HTTP_OK
    );
  }
}
```

**Front end**

```
async verfyEmail() {
      try {
        const params = new URLSearchParams(this.$route.query)
        let res = await this.$axios.get(
          'verify-email/' +
            this.$route.params.id +
            '/' +
            this.$route.params.hash,
          { params }
        )
        this.$router.push({ name: 'platform-dashboard' })
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.response)
        this.$router.push({ name: 'platform-dashboard' })
      }
    }
```